# Retrieving the reports from my Google Analytics account

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-analytics, rubygems, google-analytics-api

What's the easiest way to get the **report** data from Google Analytics  specifically from  eCommerce section? I found a few gems such as google-api-client, gabba, gattica and levato. But which one is de-facto and easier to use isn't clear.

Or if not to use a gem, what API end points should I use? From Google documentation it isn't clear either.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean by "gem"?  Is this an actual term in regards to Google Accounts?  Or are you simply saying "something good"?  Sounds like you are trying to get data out of Analytics.  Will you use it for processing?  Or end reporting the actual charts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to want to use the [Core Reporting API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/) to get that report data, and you're going to want to specifically use [ecommerce dimensions and metrics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=ecommerce) when making the request(s).

To get a sense for what types of data you can get and what parameters you need to use to get that data, I suggest playing around with the [Query Explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/). Once you understand what you're after, making the requests shouldn't be too much trouble.

I don't know of a gem that does this off hand, but honestly, you don't need one. Maybe find a gem hand handles OAuth2 for you, but after that making the requests is pretty straight-forward.